# Recover deleted folder that's still loaded by an active process

Tags: linux, process, backup, lsof

I'm really sorry if this question was asked before. I really need help with this as it involves very important data and I've been unable to do it for the past 2 hours.

Essentially I accidentally removed the wrong folder due to a typo when running rm -r. From what I know the files are still there, but the links are removed. Since the process that was using these files is still running it seems like they can still be accessed for now, until the process is ended (then they should be lost forever). I have been trying for the past 2 hours or so to write the data from the process to a folder to restore the files. But can only find how to do it for single files.

The output when running `lsof | grep ./` still shows all the files and sizes. Making me believe that it's still possible to recover it. The process itself also seems to be able to access the files just fine, as the program is still working as it should even though the links are gone.

I tried the method where you use `cp /proc/32184/fd/103 ./resoration`, but this only restores a single file it seems. Is there a way to quickly restore all the files without having to shut down the server and risk losing it?

I've made some manual backups of some of the data, but the size is too big to do it for all of it.

Thanks a whole whole whole lot to the person who can help me with this, and once again sorry if it's been asked before.

Comment: @Torin I'm afraid you can't do that on any modern system. It used to work for a while (with `ln -L`, a.k.a `linkat(…, AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW)`), but got [disabled in 2.6.39](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=aae8a97d3ec30788790d1720b71d76fd8eb44b73). See [this answer including comments](https://serverfault.com/a/238431/435589) for some discussion.

Comment: @TooTea ah, good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try scripting it yourself:

```
PID=..your process..
export RESTORE_TO_DIR=some_place
find "/proc/$PID/fd" -lname '* (deleted)' -printf '%p %l\0' |
xargs -0 sh -c '
   for l; do
      f=${l%% *}; t="$RESTORE_TO_DIR${l#* }"
      echo mkdir -p "${t%/*}" && echo cp -vb "$f" "${t% (deleted)}"
   done
' sh
```

Remove the `echo`s from before `mkdir` and `cp` if it looks OK. If you set `RESTORE_TO_DIR` to an empty string, it *should* restore the deleted files at their original place.

---

Contrary to some opinions, you cannot create hard links to deleted files (inodes not referenced from any directory).

Comment: Would this method allow me to keep the file names? From what I found it seems like links are gone, making it impossible to revert to the original file names. I'm fairly inexperienced with linux though so aside from some basic shell and usage I don't know too much.

Comment: How are the links gone? If a process opens a file and then deletes it, `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` will be a symlink with a target like `/absolute/path/to/the/original (deleted)`. If the link is rather something like `type:[number]`, it never was a regular file, but something else like a socket. Please run my script (it doesn't change anything until you remove the echoes, as explained), and paste part of its output in your question.

Comment: If the deleted files are still referenced via a memory mapping instead of a file descriptor, you will similarly have `/proc/<pid>/map_files/<mem_range>` => `/path/to/file (deleted)` symlinks.

Comment: Seems like it did manage to restore some of the files, not all of them though. I'm guessing the others might just be permanently gone? Good catch though, from what I read most people said it wasn't possible at all!